# Ruby File to String Issues

Tags: ruby, file-io

I have a need to split up an html file so that I can target Nokogiri on a specific section.  So I need to open the file, and read it into a variable.

```
source = File.open("Company_example.html", "rb")
contents = source.read

puts contents.class               ==> String
puts contents.length              ==> 0
puts File.readable?("Company_example.html")     ==> true
```

The file is there, and I've been working with it for the past 2 hours.  I can't figure this one out.  Any advice appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Can you write the output of `File.stat("Company_example.html")` ?

Comment: Or try absoluate path?

Comment: I tried absolute path, and it didn't do anything.  Also, it's already viewed by the current output.  Here is the output with that File.stat at the end:`String
0
true
#<File::Stat:0x007f8dc1022028>`

Comment: Solution: Grabbing a source file (doc) then shoving it into a Nokogiri object, then asking it to be brought into a File.read will not work.  I have to find out how to copy the source into an independent variable.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Grabbing a source file (doc) then shoving it into a Nokogiri object, then asking it to be brought into a File.read will not work. I have to find out how to copy the source into an independent variable.